# testing whether a variable or control seq. is a box in LaTeX3

Tags: latex3, expl3

Is there a way, in LaTeX3, to find out whether a given control sequence or variable is a box register (created with `\box_new:(cN)`)?

Comment: You can test with `\box_if_exist:NTF`, but this doesn't really test if the control sequence has been created with `\box_new:N`. There isn't a `\boxdef` primitive in TeX: box registers are accessed only with integers. So `\box_new:N` actually defines an integer constant.

Comment: @egreg: Thanks. If a subsequent `\box_if_empty_p:N` evaluates to false, can I be sure the tested integer is a box?

Comment: No. If the tested integer is the constant 32000, for instance, it addresses box register 32000 even if not defined with `\box_new:N`

Comment: At present, we don't track the names of boxes other than using the plain/LaTex2e like approach of assigning a number for a box (as @egreg outlines). However, we could in principal add a list of these to the internal LaTeX3 information, and then query that. What I guess would needed is a use case.

Comment: Probably the best is to rely on one's own defined variables. There's no problem in allocating new ones, so long as they are a bit less than 32768.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At present, we don't track the names of boxes other than using the plain/LaTex2e like approach of assigning a number for a box (as @egreg outlines in a comment). However, we could in principle add a list of these to the internal LaTeX3 information, and then query that. What I guess would needed is a use case. That would be a feature request for `expl3`, so should be requested *via* the [GitHub issues system](https://github.com/latex3/svn-mirror/issues)